Svelte 5 multiple named slots in +layout.svelte
I have taught tutorials about multiple props to component, but I want to use it in +layout.
I hope to insert multiple different components into the specified {@render} of the upper layout (+layout.svelte, not a component) at different routing sub-levels (some +page.svelte files) as like as svelte4 multi named slot.
I currently use the following code to solve the needs, but I intuitively think that my way is bad and very circuitous, and I do not need to dynamically change the inserted components after loading the page. Now I use additional code to pass these snippets via context methods, is there a better way to simplify them?
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import { setContext, createRawSnippet } from 'svelte';
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

  const dummySnippet = (text: string) =>
    createRawSnippet(() => {
      return { render: () => text };
    });

  let { children } = $props();

  let slotLeft = writable(dummySnippet('LEFT'));
  let slotCenter = writable(dummySnippet('CENTER'));
  let slotRight = writable(dummySnippet('RIGHT'));

  setContext('LayoutSlot', { slotLeft, slotCenter, slotRight });
</script>

<winbox class="flex flex-row h-full w-full overflow-hidden">
  <listbox class="w-[400px]">
    {@render $slotLeft()}
  </listbox>

  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col border-x">
    {@render $slotCenter()}
  </div>

  <div class="w-[350px]">
    {@render $slotRight()}
  </div>
</winbox>

{@render children()}

<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount, getContext, type Snippet } from 'svelte';
  import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store';

  let {
    slotLeft,
    slotCenter,
    slotRight
  }: {
    slotLeft: Writable<Snippet>;
    slotCenter: Writable<Snippet>;
    slotRight: Writable<Snippet>;
  } = getContext('LayoutSlot');

  onMount(() => {
    $slotLeft = menuLeft;
    $slotCenter = mainContent;
    $slotRight = menuRight;
  });
</script>

{#snippet menuLeft()}
  <p>Left Menu Pending</p>
{/snippet}

{#snippet mainContent()}
  <p>Center Content Pending</p>
{/snippet}

{#snippet menuRight()}
  <p>Right Menu Pending</p>
{/snippet}

<children>TEST</children>

<!-- .... other option snippets from other routing-->
<!-- {#snippet foo1()} -->
<!-- {#snippet foo2()} -->

Hopefully someone can give me idea for better than my current approach to simplify the codes, maybe there should be a direct way to pass props (not only default children props) in the +page.svelte inside html area, but I can't find it.

This just isn't really supported.
Before Svelte 5 you could not do this at all and this is rather hacky. It does not work properly with server-side rendering because the rendering of the layout finishes before the page can send content back up.
There is a way to work around this by running the page first, not rendering anything in it, then render the slots from the context. (Found by zyxd on GitHub.)
E.g.
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte';

  const { children } = $props();

  const slots = {};
  setContext('layout-slots', slots);
</script>

<!--
  Run page logic first, this should not output anything
  and only set slots in the context.
-->
{@render children()}

<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    {@render slots.left()}
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    {@render slots.right()}
  </div>
</div>

{@render slots.children()}

<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
  import { getContext } from 'svelte';

  // This block could be extracted to a function taking the slots
  // as arguments for convenience.
  const slots = getContext('layout-slots');
  slots.left = left;
  slots.right = right;
  slots.children = children;
</script>

{#snippet left()}
  <div>Left slot</div>
{/snippet}

{#snippet right()}
  <div>Right slot</div>
{/snippet}

{#snippet children()}
  <div>Children slot</div>
{/snippet}

Alternatively, create a component with the necessary slots and use that in every page instead of doing this via the +layout.svelte.

Thanks for your answer, based on your opinion, is my current code already the correct solution? I'm a newbie and hope to get more advice from yo， thanks again

You could use a regular component instead of a +layout. You would have to use it in every page that previously automatically got the layout, but it would support any number of slots. (If you have SSR, I would not really recommend the current approach.)

You are right, gave me a good tip, I will re-imagine this code. ssr is not concern in this project, finally it will be static pages fetch datatable and work with tauri for a inhouse desktop app.

@LuxHK: Someone on GitHub came up with an approach to context-driven scenarios that works with SSR. I added an example for completeness, in case you find that preferable.

I just saw your code. thanks again! It's a great idea to send objects through setcontext.
In addition, the example you mentioned in github is the  svelte-store-router?

@LuxHK: It's this answer dealing with communication between Select & SelectItem components.

Thanks, I will study it carefully @brunnerh

The lastest update by brunnerh advice (+layout used)： https://stackoverflow.com/a/79136969/28040664
so, Now I have two options that both satisfy my requirements，the code below is another option.

I'm glad to get brunnerh's advice. I can now structure the code more rationally. I only need to make a WinBox component containing the layout div with {@render} and introduce the predefined snippet props.
Pass {snippet} into the WinBox component on +page.svelte. Maybe I need to go a step further to replace snippet with component and pass it into WinBox with very few changes.
I guess I am closer to svelte5. The following code is what I'm doing.
// WinBox.svelte

<script lang="ts">
    import type { Snippet } from 'svelte';

    let {
        children,
        slotLeft = dummySnippet,
        slotCenter = dummySnippet,
        slotRight = dummySnippet
    }: {
        children?: Snippet;
        slotLeft?: Snippet;
        slotCenter?: Snippet;
        slotRight?: Snippet;
    } = $props();
</script>

{#snippet dummySnippet()}
    <p>Pending</p>
{/snippet}

<winbox class="flex flex-row h-full w-full overflow-hidden">
    <listbox class="w-[400px]">
        {@render slotLeft()}
    </listbox>

    <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col border-x">
        {@render slotCenter()}
    </div>

    <div class="w-[350px]">
        {@render slotRight()}
    </div>
</winbox>

{@render children?.()}

// +page.svelte

<script lang="ts">
    import { WinBox } from '$lib/components/my-ui/win-box';
</script>

{#snippet slotLeft()}
    <p>Left Menu Pending</p>
{/snippet}

{#snippet slotCenter()}
    <p>Center Content Pending</p>
{/snippet}

{#snippet slotRight()}
    <p>Right Menu Pending</p>
{/snippet}

<WinBox {slotLeft} {slotCenter} {slotRight}>This area is the children prop snippet</WinBox>

